# Adding Elements to doubly-linked lists

Tags: c, struct, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to use a while loop to add elements to a doubly linked list. The nodes are being made, but they all store the same word, which is the very last word of the file I am reading. Here's my while loop:

```
while(fscanf(text, "%s", word) == 1)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp = new_node(word); //Creates a new node
    temp->prev = cursor; //Cursor represents current position in linked list
    temp->next = NULL;
    cursor->next = temp;
    cursor = temp;
}
```

The cursor is initialized to the head of the list before the start of the while loop.

And here is my node struct:

```
struct node
{
    struct node* prev;
    struct word_entry* data;
    struct node* next;
};
```

What is wrong with my while loop? Why does it keep overwriting previous nodes? Please and thank you!

Comment: The bug is probably in `new_node()` which you haven't shown us.

Comment: `temp = new_node(word);` --> `temp = new_node(strdup(word));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is in `text` and you're loading your words in a char array called `word`.

Since your loop assigns all nodes to this same array, `temp = new_node(word);` all nodes point to same char array.

When you read last word from file into `word`, since all nodes are pointing to it, they all read out same word.

You must allocate separate word storage per node, and copy word to that storage while assigning to node:

```
nodeword = malloc(strlen(word) + 1);
if(nodeword) {
  strcpy(nodeword, word);
  nodeword[strlen(word)] = 0;
  temp = new_node(nodeword);
}
else {
  break;
}
```

or strdup() if you will..